# How to fix ifstream syntax error, and possible loss of data conversion error in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, error-handling, compiler-errors

I have code from the Source.cpp file for my code. I'm in the middle of this lab which I create an inventory that tracks a camera store. It's almost completed, but I am having error C4244 (Possible loss of data using = on like 24) and error C3867 (ios::base_fail/ios::basic_ifstream). I will write "HERE" next to where the error came up since I can't tell you what line. Here is the code in question:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<fstream>
#include "LinkedList.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
LinkedList ll; // Creating object of linked list

struct info record;

char dataToBeRead[100];

ifstream fp; 

fp.open("fileInventory.txt");

if (fp.fail) !!!HERE!!! 
{
    cout << "The file cannot be opened\n";
}
else


{
    while (fp.open, dataToBeRead[100] != NULL) !!!HERE!!!
    {
        char *token = strtok(dataToBeRead, " "); 
        strcpy(record.camera, token); 
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        record.price = atof(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        record.quantity1 = atoi(token); !!!HERE!!! (possible loss of data?)
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        record.quantity2 = atoi(token);
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        ll.addEnd(record);
        ll.addReverse(record);

    }
    int ch = 0;
    char camera[50];
    float price;
    int quantity1;
    int quantity2;
    do //Must open the menu
    {
        cout << "1. Display the inventory in alphabetic order:\n";
        cout << "2. Display the inventory in reverse alphabetic order:\n";
        cout << "3. Add an item to the inventory:\n";
        cout << "4. Delete an item from inventory:\n";
        cout << "5. Change any info for an item:\n";
        cout << "6. Exit:\n";
        cin >> ch;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            ll.showList1();
            break;
        case 2:
            ll.showList2();
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Enter camera:\n";
            cin >> camera;
            cout << "Enter price:\n";
            cin >> price;
            cout << "Enter quantity1:\n";
            cin >> quantity1;
            cout << "Enter quantity2:\n";
            cin >> quantity2;
            strcpy(record.camera, camera);
            record.price = price;
            record.quantity1 = quantity1;
            record.quantity2 = quantity2;
            ll.addEnd(record);
            ll.addReverse(record);
            ll.showList1();
            ll.showList2();
            break;
        case 4:
            cout << "Enter camera name to be deleted:\n";
            cin >> camera;
            ll.removeValue1(camera);
            ll.removeValue2(camera);
            ll.showList1();
            ll.showList2();
            break;
        case 5:
            cout << "Enter the camera name for which you want to edit details:\n";
            cin >> camera;
            cout << "Enter price:\n";
            cin >> price;
            cout << "Enter quantity1:\n";
            cin >> quantity1;
            cout << "Enter quantity2:\n";
            cin >> quantity2;
            ll.editList(camera, price, quantity1, quantity2);
            break;
        case 6:
            break;

        }
    } while (ch != 6); // Menu will run until the ch is not 6


    ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("newlist.txt"); 

    if (myfile.fail) !!!HERE!!!
    {
        exit(1);
    }

}

return 1;
}
```

It's clearly an issue with fstream but I don't know what I'm doing wrong. And I'm unsure why there would be a possible loss of data specifically on that line. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: `while (fp.open, dataToBeRead[100] != NULL)`  -- Explain what you're trying to do here.

Comment: while the file is open, get the data as long as the file is not null

Comment: No, not even close.  That is not how you read a line from a file until the end-of-file.

Comment: Okay, are you going to explain how to do that correctly? That's why I'm asking for help.

Comment: I'm very much a beginner at C++

Comment: You could start by using `std::string dataToBeRead;` instead of char arrays.  That would make things much simpler by using `while (std::getline(fp, dataToBeRead))`.

Comment: Sarah: Minor simplification: `std::ifstream fp("fileInventory.txt"); if (fp) ...` My own take on resourse management is that I loath `open`/`close` (and their ilks) in production code.

Comment: Did you look up the compiler error C3867? It's telling you that `fp.fail` and `fp.open` are functions and you're not calling them, you're referring to them as pointers to the functions.

Answer (score 1):

Needless to say, this line:

`while (fp.open, dataToBeRead[100] != NULL)`

is not correct.

Also, to test if the file opened successfully or not, you could simply do this:

```
if (!fp)
{
    // file failed to open
}
```

But overall, the simplest way is to not introduce char arrays at all, and instead use `std::string`:

```
  std::string dataToBeRead;
  while (std::getline(fp, dataToBeRead)) 
  {
   //...
  }
```

Given that `dataToBeRead` is now a `std::string`, the logic to tokenize needs to change.  That is simply done by using [std::istringstream](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and using `operator >>`.

```
std::istringstream strm(dataToBeRead);
strm >> record.camera >> record.price >> record.quantity1 >> record.quantity2;
ll.addEnd(record);
ll.addReverse(record);
```

Thus the entire loop is this:

```
  #include <sstream>
  //...
  std::string dataToBeRead;
  while (std::getline(fp, dataToBeRead)) 
  {
     std::istringstream strm(dataToBeRead);
     strm >> record.camera >> record.price >> record.quantity1 >> record.quantity2;
     ll.addEnd(record);
     ll.addReverse(record);
  }
```

This is far more easier and safer than using C-style `strtok` processing.

---

You could also skip the entire creation of the string by directly reading the input using `operator >>`:

```
  while (fp >> record.camera >> record.price >> record.quantity1 >> record.quantity2)
  {
     ll.addEnd(record);
     ll.addReverse(record);
  }
```

You usually want to use this method if the parsing of the data is simple (in your case, it is separated using spaces).  If anything more complex than that, then the usage of the `istringstream` could be utilized.

Comment: There's no need to re-declare the string stream in every iteration of the loop.  It is best moved out of the while.

Comment: @CodeLurker You could do that, but that would require a `str("")` call.

Comment: @SarahSmith The best _thanks_ you can give is to accept the answer that got your question resolved.